# How can I create a bar code without an enter?

Tags: barcode-scanner, barcode

I know I can install code 3 of 9 font to create a bar code. If I type the number 12, and change the font, when I scan it, it is the same as entering 12 then hitting enter on a scanner.

Is the Enter part of the bar code or something inherent in the scanner?  If in the scanner, do most have the option to add the enter or not?

Is it possible to have bar codes with and bar codes without an enter?  I may not be asking things as clearly as I'd like.

Comment: I don't think `Enter` would be part of your code, it is attached by the reader

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Enter</kbd> is not a part of the barcode, Code 39 barcodes contain only alphanumeric characters and some punctuation (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39)). It's the barcode reader that inserts the <kbd>Enter</kbd> character for convenience to submit forms when scanning is finished. Your scanner can probably be reconfigured to send different "end of barcode" character or to disable it completely, check manual to see how to use it.